# How to mount drives to access them via XnView or other software

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, nautilus, workflow

I'm new to Ubuntu and just installed a fresh system parallel to my win 10 system. I separated both on different flash drives which are connected internally to the mainboard.

Within Nautilus (the file manager app which comes with ubuntu) I can access the drives as shown:

[image: Nautilus screenshot, add relevant information here.]

But when I'm in XnView, which has its own file management viewer, I can't find the correct path to the mounted drives.

[image: XnView of root partition, add relevant information here.]

How can I mount these drives so that I can access them from XnView and other software?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to `/media/(your-username)/(drive-label)` after it's mounted. As long as you don't have too many drives plugged in, if you don't know the drive label you can dig around pretty easy to find what you want.

Also, if this is on a live system the `(your-username)` part will be `ubuntu`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Good morning, in nautilus there is indeed a path for the “raid 1” and “raid 2” partitions and drives I have attached externally. But there is just an empty folder with its name. But the partition “LinuxSSD-Data” which I set up extra for saving data separated from the system partition does not show up here. The same is with “Cache” partition. And all drives are still mounted. Within Nautilus I can access the mounted drives via /mnt.

Comment: Have you tried this with XNView MP? It doesn't seem to be able to see any mounted filesystems on my machine, whether it's under /media/$USER/ or another mount point. It can't follow symlinks into the filesystems either. I'm thinking it has something to do with the snap sandbox.